# Sharepoint List Instance : populate multichoice Element.xml

Tags: xml, list, sharepoint

I created a list with an instance.
I have a column of type MultiChoice and I would like populer my list element.xml
What format should I use to add multiple items in my column MultiChoice ?

```
    <Row>
      <Field Name="Title">Test</Field>          
      <Field Name="SubTypes">MultiChoice1, MultiChoice2, MultiChoice3</Field>
    </Row>
```

It's for the field subtypes, I want to add more items.
I tried with "," with ";" or ";#" but without result.

I know that when you've a lookup field, you use ";#" but on a multichoice field idon't know...

Any Ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
<Field Name="SubTypes">;#MultiChoice1;#MultiChoice2;#MultiChoice3;#</Field>
```

Cheers

Truez